# Possible memory leak when using an inner closure

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

I want to make sure i don't have a memory leak with the following. Now in order to throw an error
 from my code while using a network call in ooder to get this to work i have to keep a reference to my `dispatchgroup` and the `function` to process the data.

```
   func myFunc(
               completion: @escaping (_ success: () throws -> Bool) -> Void) {

                let fG = DispatchGroup()
                let processLinks = self.processDownloadData
                requestDownloadLinks(fromURL: url) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        processLinks(data, fG, stagingBundle, {_ in
                            switch result {
                            case .failure(let error):
                                completion({ throw error })
                            case .success:
                                completion({ return true })
                            }
                        })
                    case .failure(let error):
                        completion({ return true }) 
                    }
                }
```

where `processDownloadData`

```
    func processDownloadData(
        data: ((urls: [(url: URL, language: String)], version: String)),
        dispatchGroup: DispatchGroup),
        completion: @escaping (_ success: () throws -> Bool) -> Void) {
//write data 
}
```

and `requestDownloadLinks`

```
  final func requestDownloadLinks(
        fromURL url: URL,
        completion: ((Result<(urls: [(url: URL, language: String)],
        version: String), Error>) -> Void)?  = nil
    ) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {return}
            self.httpManager?.get(url: url) {result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    if let completion = completion {
                        completion(.failure(LokalisationError.network(originatingError: error)))
                    }
                case .success(let data):
                    do {
                        guard let data = data as? Data else {
                            if let completion = completion {
                                completion(.failure(LokalisationError.malformedDataFromServer))
                            }
                            return
                        }
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let contents = try decoder.decode(EndPointResponse.self, from: data)
                        if let data = contents.data {
                            let urls = data.map { URL(string: $0.url) ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: "") }
                            let language = data.map { $0.language }
                            let urlsForLang = Array(zip(urls, language))
                            if let completion = completion {
                                completion(.success( (urlsForLang, contents.version) ))
                            }
                        }
                    } catch let error {
                        if let completion = completion {
                            completion(.failure(LokalisationError.network(originatingError: error)))
                        }

     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now by doing this am I creating a memory leak? When I create the reference to the `dispatchgroup` and the function I think that they do not get released until the http call is finished. Now this is ok, since it will either complete successfully or error. Or does this cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DispatchGroup will live until `completion()` is finished in `requestDownloadLinks` unless you do something funny in `processDownloadData` with it. You're passing it as a reference from the `myFunc()` to `requestDownloadLinks` via a closure block inside which you call the `processDownloadData` passing the DispatchGroup to it. If it isn't passed on or held as a reference otherwise inside it, you're probably safe. To be sure profile your app with Instruments and check for memory allocations and zombies. Also you can check the memory footprint in the debugger. If you call myfunc many times you should see a steady increase in memory.